# Melhor Performance no Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, desempenho

Eu fiz uma condição dessa forma:

```
If @dt_contabilizacao = @dt_operacional And Not Exists (Select 1 From tabela Where      dt_mes_referencia = @mes_referencia)
```

Mas a verificação da dt não é necessária já que se existir dado daquele mês ele já não insere, então deixei assim:

```
If Not Exists (Select 1 From tabela Where dt_mes_referencia = @mes_referencia)
```

Dai surgiu uma dúvida, se eu jogar esse resultado em uma variável que vai conter '1' ou ser nula, caso ela seja nula vai inserir, então faria essa condição no If, porém não sei se isso é uma maneira de melhorar a performance do script ou da na mesma, poderiam tirar essa dúvida por favor?

Comment: Porque não colocar a condição diretamente no comando `INSERT`?

Answer (score 4):

Não vejo diferença de desempenho entre as construções

```
-- código #1
IF not exists (SELECT * from tabela where dt_mes_referencia = @mes_referencia)
   INSERT ...
```

e

```
-- código #2 v2
declare @Var bit;
set @Var= case when (exists (SELECT * from tabela where dt_mes_referencia = @mes_referencia))
                   then 'true' else 'false' end;    
IF @Var = 'false'
  INSERT ...
```

Teoricamente a segunda construção teria desempenho pior, por causa da necessidade de alocar memória para a variável, armazenar valor na variável e depois recuperar o conteúdo dela; mas esta diferença é nula, na prática, pois o principal gargalo em banco de dados é o acesso ao disco.

Entretanto, a segunda construção pode ser vantajosa caso a condição tenha que ser verificada mais de uma vez no mesmo trecho de código SQL, reduzindo assim o acesso ao disco.